# Hibernate nested where in clause in order by clause

Tags: sql, hibernate, sql-order-by, where-in

I'm trying to convert the following query from sql to hibernate and I'm having not luck.

```
select * from person order by (person_id in (1,4,7)), last_name;
```

The ids are an example of some input values that will probably come from some sort of Collection.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass list as parameter for in query, rest of the query will be same, one of the below query should work.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Person order by (persionId in (:ids)), lastName").setParameterList("ids", idList);
```

OR

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Person order by (CASE WHEN persionId in (:ids) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), lastName").setParameterList("ids", idList);
```

Comment: Thanks alot!  The first suggestion didn't work for me but the second one did.